# SUMIF equivalent with unique date ranges in Python (Summing if date falls within various date ranges for variable creation)

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, sumifs

I am looking to create variables that sum based on date ranges unique to different features / categories to automate a current Excel task in Python.  It is like a SUMIF in Excel but unique date ranges for different variables.  I`ll try to recreate a similar situation as I cannot share the exact data.  At the moment, I have a sales dataframe with sales per week by area like so:

| Week | Area | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08/02/2019 | London | 200 |
| 08/02/2019 | Scotland | 150 |
| 15/02/2019 | London | 100 |
| 15/02/2019 | Scotland | 120 |
| 22/02/2019 | London | 50 |
| 22/02/2019 | Scotland | 20 |

I want to incorporate whether the date falls within sales periods for products, so say I have another dataframe like this:

| Product | Sale Start Week | Sale End Week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Boots | 08/02/2019 | 15/02/2019 |
| Accessories | 15/02/2019 | 22/02/2019 |

I want to create something that sums if the dates fall within those specified for each product.  For example, for Boots below, sum Sales if the weeks in Sales fall within the Sales Periods date range:

| Area | Boots | Accessories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | 300 | 150 |
| Scotland | 270 | 140 |

I`ve tried groupby and a pivot table but I am not sure how to incorporate the sales dates filters into it.  At the moment, the sales period dataframe and the sales dataframe are separate.

This is what I have for the pivot code which is almost there:

```
test = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Area','Week'],columns=sales_period_df['Product'],values=['Sales'],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

But this doesnt include filtering for the sales periods and I`m not sure how to incorporate this.  Would appreciate your advice, thanks in advance!

Comment: the summarized total sales (860) exceeds the sales in the first DF (640).

Comment: Could you please describe the inner logic of periods? Can periods for different products overlap? If so, then what is the nature of Sales? If not, then do all the periods cover the time in the Sales data frame?

Comment: This is an example I have tried to translate so apologies if I`ve confused you.  Periods can overlap.  The idea is to count how many sales there were during each sales period, all the periods cover the weeks in the full Sales dataframe.  The main aim is to sum by weeks which fall in given ranges.  I know how to do it for one or two, but given that I have a lot of products, there are a lot of varying dates (but all within the range of the Sales dataframe) @Vitalizzare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to overlapping periods, we can't use the classic pivoting in this case (unless we duplicate overlapping sales records for each period, wich seems too much). So we have to create this table manually.

To start, let's prepare some data to work with:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''Week,Area,Sales
08/02/2019,London,200
08/02/2019,Scotland,150
15/02/2019,London,100
15/02/2019,Scotland,120
22/02/2019,London,50
22/02/2019,Scotland,20'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True).sort_index()

data = '''Product,Sale Start Week,Sale End Week
Boots,08/02/2019,15/02/2019
Accessories,15/02/2019,22/02/2019
Something,08/02/2019,22/02/2019'''

sales_period_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=0, parse_dates=[1, 2], dayfirst=True)
```

The structure of `df` and `sales_period_df` is slightly modified so that `Week` and `Product` are now indexes.

Next, we prepare the output frame and supportive data:

```
import pandas.IndexSlice as idx

# create slices from sales_period_df
# which can be used to locate data in df
periods = sales_period_df.agg(lambda row: idx[row['Sale Start Week']:row['Sale End Week']], axis=1)

# separate sales by area
sales_by_area = df.groupby('Area')['Sales']

# create the output DataFrame with unique areas as indexes 
# and products as columns
output = pd.DataFrame(index=df['Area'].unique(), columns=sales_period_df.index)
```

To fill in the data, we can use eather `apply` or `agg` like this:

```
for product in output.columns:
    output[product] = sales_by_area.agg(lambda sales: sales.loc[periods[product]].sum())
```

Let's assemble the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import IndexSlice as idx
from io import StringIO

data = '''Week,Area,Sales
08/02/2019,London,200
08/02/2019,Scotland,150
15/02/2019,London,100
15/02/2019,Scotland,120
22/02/2019,London,50
22/02/2019,Scotland,20'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True).sort_index()

data = '''Product,Sale Start Week,Sale End Week
Boots,08/02/2019,15/02/2019
Accessories,15/02/2019,22/02/2019
Something,08/02/2019,22/02/2019'''

sales_period_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=0, parse_dates=[1, 2], dayfirst=True)

periods = sales_period_df.agg(lambda row: idx[row['Sale Start Week']:row['Sale End Week']], axis=1)
output = pd.DataFrame(index=df['Area'].unique(), columns=sales_period_df.index)
sales_by_area = df.groupby('Area')['Sales']

for product in output.columns:
    output[product] = sales_by_area.agg(lambda sales: sales.loc[periods[product]].sum())

print(output)
```

Output:

```
Product   Boots  Accessories  Something
London      300          150        350
Scotland    270          140        290
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# DF: sales (top DF in question)
# DF2: sales period (second DF in question)

# format the date into datetime
df['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Week'], dayfirst=True)
df2[['Sale Start Week','Sale End Week']]=df2[['Sale Start Week','Sale End Week']].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)
df2

# merge using merge_asof 
df3=pd.merge_asof( df.sort_values('Week'),
                  df2.sort_values('Sale Start Week'),
                  left_on = 'Week',
                  right_on='Sale Start Week')

# including only when week falls within end week
df3=df3.loc[df3['Week'] <= df3['Sale End Week']]
df3

# cross tab for resultset
out= (pd.crosstab(index=df3['Area'], 
                  columns=df3['Product'], 
                  values=df3['Sales'], 
                  aggfunc='sum')
      .reset_index()
      .rename_axis(columns=None))

out
```

```
    Area    Accessories     Boots
0   London      150         200
1   Scotland    140         150
```

Comment: The output is different from expected. Why do you think that `merge_asof` is applicable here?

Comment: merge_asof to get an unequal join. the summary total of sales (860) in the OP dont match the sales (640) in OP  @Vitalizzare

Comment: If you assume that "Sale end week" is not included in the period, then "Accessories" in your answer should be [100, 120], not [150, 140].

Comment: @Vitalizzare, not sure how OP wants it to have. In any case, it shouldn't be counted twice

Answer (score 0):

One option is to compute the non-equi join with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join)  to get matches, and finally groupby and sum:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(dates
.conditional_join(
    products, 
    ('Week', 'Sale Start Week', '>='), 
    ('Week', 'Sale End Week', '<='),
    # for larger data, numba may offer 
    # better performance
    use_numba = False, 
    df_columns=['Area','Sales'], 
    right_columns='Product')
.pivot_table(
    index='Area',
    columns='Product',
    values='Sales',
    aggfunc='sum')
)
Product   Accessories  Boots
Area                        
London            150    300
Scotland          140    270
```